# How to ensure that removed allowed ports will be removed using Ansible's UFW module?

Tags: ansible

The [UFW module document](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ufw_module.html) has been read, but it is unclear how to let ansible remove ports that are not defined anymore.

It works to add new ports, but now 5 ports have been removed and I do not want to login to each of the more than 50 servers.

It is possible to write some custom exec, but I would like to use the Ansible's UFW module's functionality. Does it support such a scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on:

> ```
> # Allow OpenSSH. (Note that as ufw manages its own state, simply removing
> # a rule=allow task can leave those ports exposed. Either use delete=yes
> # or a separate state=reset task)
> ```

The following snippet was added to the top of the file:

```
---
- name: Reset UFW
  ufw:
    state: reset
```

Once ansible was run:

```
TASK [rolename : Reset UFW]
```

the undefined ports were removed